# matplotlib: reduce the number of labels on piechart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a piechart with so many slices, that is very hard to read it:
[image]

Is it possible to reduce the number of slices, by grouping the smallest portions in one named "others" or just hide them?

Comment: Just for thinking about it - perhaps a pie chart is simply not the right choice for your data. Consider/play around with different visualizations (bar(h) chart, for example, or even a scatter plot, if you have perhaps even more properties to show besides the percentage value...)